# Transaction independent writes inside a trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, trigger, sql-server-express

I am using sql express 2008 r2 express edition.

Is it possible to do writes inside a trigger independent from the the transaction of the statement which causes the trigger to fire?

I have triggers working for simple auditing on some tables in my DB. I have one table for keeping the auditing data (Look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx) for details) It works fine except i don't want the auditing data be vanished when the transaction rolledback. So I want to write audit data to audit table independent from the transaction of the statement that causes my auditing trigger to fire.

Comment: Just in case an Oracle user ever stumbles across this question - you can do this in Oracle using an autonomous transaction.

Comment: Technically this can be accomplished via dynamic SQL, but I would not do it. IMO is is way easier to handle errors and implement auditing logic outside the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add a linked server to your own sever.  On the linked server, disable transactions.  Any calls made to the linked server will now run in their own transaction.

Example setup:

```
-- Add linked server called LOCALHOST
USE [master]
IF  EXISTS (SELECT srv.name FROM sys.servers srv WHERE srv.server_id != 0 AND srv.name = N'LOCALHOST')
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'LOCALHOST', @droplogins='droplogins'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LOCALHOST', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
-- Allow procedure calls
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LOCALHOST', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
-- But do not allow the procedure calls to enlist in our transaction
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LOCALHOST', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'LOCALHOST', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'true'

-- Create a test procedure
use TestDatabase
if exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'Log')
    drop table log
if exists (select * from sys.procedures where name = 'WriteLog')
    drop procedure WriteLog
go
create table log (id int identity, message varchar(256))
go
create procedure WriteLog
as
insert Log (message) values ('Hello World!')
go
```

Test code:

```
-- Insert through a direct call, and then through a linked server call
begin transaction
exec TestDatabase.dbo.WriteLog
exec [Localhost].TestDatabase.dbo.WriteLog
rollback transaction

select * from Log
```

The `select` will show only 1 row.  The `rollback` has not undone the effefcts of the linked server call.

While a nice trick, this is probably not something you'd want to do inside a production environment.  Personally I'd only allow data modifications through a stored procedure, and add logging in the stored procedure itself, before it starts a transaction (if any.)

Answer (score 1):

Use Service Broker to decouple the transaction from the log write.

That is, [push the change info onto the Service broker queue to be consumed by some listener](http://sqlserverplanet.com/design/triggers-service-broker-cdc-or-change-tracking). More sample code in [this dba.se answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10560/630)

Comment: I don't think it is possible in express editions

Comment: hmm. It can consume but not send. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559905/using-service-broker-with-sql-server-express-2008

Comment: I'd expect `rollback transaction` to roll back any messages pushed to a queue?

Comment: @Andomar: AFAIK, it doesn't.