# What interval does SQL Server Profiler's "duration" refer to?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, profiler

I've been having strange things on a production server. Clients (all on the local LAN) are getting *timeout* errors on queries that should have no problem at all.

- it happens during times of low CPU usage (<1%)
- and when there is low hard drive I/O (<1%)

I spent an afternoon watching traces live in SQL Server Profiler, and the absolute epitome of the non-sense was the batch:

```
SELECT GETDATE() As ServerDate
```

Where profiler shows the numbers:

- **CPU:** 0
- **Reads:** 0
- **Writes:** 0
- **Duration**: 17,130 *ms*
- **StartTime:** 2017-02-28 15:00:20.777
- **EndTime:** 2017-02-28 15:00:37.907

[image]

What can possibly be going on in this database engine that perfectly benign queries take too long?

- anti-virus software?
- a VMWare hypervisor that doesn't schedule the virtual machine for 17 seconds?
- a kernel model stall for 17 seconds that doesn't show up in Task Manager?

Because even if the server *were* busy, a query that takes:

- zero cpu
- zero reads
- zero writes
- and has no side effect on any pages in memory

should not take 17 seconds to complete.

### Duration

The only way forward is to try to figure out what `duration` **means**.

What does duration **mean**? Is it:

- Start: after entire batch has been received by the database engine
- End: after the query is complete

or is it:

- Start: after entire batch has been received by the database engine
- End: after the last byte has been *sent* to the client

or is it:

- Start: after entire batch has been received by the database engine
- End: after the last byte has been *received* by the client

(but then how does SQL Server know when the last byte has been *"received"* by the client).

Because given that:

- there's nothing wrong on the server
- there's nothing wrong on the database
- there's nothing wrong on the client

there must be something wrong in between. So I need to know exactly what conceptual events SQL Server uses to denote the *start* and *end*.

### Locks

- Duration from SQL Server 2005 traces is *stored* (i.e. when you save the trace to a table or file) in microseconds (one-millionth of a second)
- Duration in Profiler is *presented* (i.e. on screen and in a screenshot) in milliseconds (one-thousandth of a second)

Of course, milliseconds vs microseconds was not my question.

Given that the only lock that `getdate()` takes is:

- Acquire: **S** (shared) lock on **D** (database)
- Release: **S** (shared) lock on **D** (database)

***If*** the issues were due to locking:

- can anyone suggest why acquiring a shared lock on a database might take 17 seconds
- and if it ***were*** due to a 17 second delay acquiring a shared database lock
- why **other** batches can continue to acquire/release shared database locks without a stall?
- and if the stall **was** due to taking 17 seconds to acquire a lock
- what I can do about it?

That also wasn't my question. My question is tautological.

### Tautology

My question as written is pretty simple:

> What does **duration** mean?

Of course that's trivial to answer:

> duration is **EndTime - StartTime**.

Which means I'm actually asking (without being pedantic):

- during what stage of query execution is **StartTime** timestamp recorded?
- during what stage of query execution is **EndTime** timestamp recorded?

If I can get an answer to that, my question next will be to find all events that go in between.

### Bonus Chatter

It might be helpful to see a timeline of all events during `select getdate()`:

1. Acquire Shared Database lock
2. Release Shared Database lock
3. SP:CacheMiss
4. SQL:BatchStarting
5. SQL:StmtStarting
6. SQL:StmtCompleted
7. SQL:BatchCompleted

Of course, this is just *one*, non-repeatable, random, example of queries that take an inordinate amount of time to run.

### Bonus Reading

- [SQL Server insert randomly takes 10+ seconds to complete?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47988/sql-server-insert-randomly-takes-10-seconds-to-complete)  *(closed by grumpy people)*
- [SQL Profiler CPU / duration units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976628/sql-profiler-cpu-duration-units) *(it's 17,000 ms)*
- [View and Analyze Traces with SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175848.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Duration from SQL Server 2005 traces is stored in microseconds (one-millionth of a second) while Duration from SQL Server 2000 is stored in milliseconds (one-thousandth of a second). CPU is always stored in milliseconds.

The typical cause for long durations with no work is blocking: someone else has a lock on a row.

To find out why queries are waiting, skip Profiler and head to Adam Machanic's sp_WhoIsActive. It shows you what queries are running right now, and the wait_info column tells you what they're waiting on (and for how long). If you see LCK*, then it's blocking.

Comment: is it only me, or does this not answer the actual question at all: during what stage of query execution are StartTime and EndTime timestamps recorded? Are resultset transmission and network time included or excluded? Can that be configured?

Comment: @dlatikay you're welcome to contribute a better answer.