# It is mandatory to create a route when creating an event notification?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I'm starting with service broker. Already managed to setup an event notification for blocked processes [based on this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34327/9031) and it's working flawlessly. Then I wanted to setup another one to [notify for deadlocks](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/07/18/Immediate-deadlock-notifications-without-changing-existing-code.aspx) and I see a `CREATE ROUTE` statement:

```
-- create the route for the service
CREATE ROUTE DeadLockNotificationsRoute
    WITH SERVICE_NAME = 'DeadLockNotificationsService',
    ADDRESS = 'LOCAL';
GO
```

But on previous one I did not ran this step, it was not included and it works. Looking on several places [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10560/9031), [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2121/event-notifications-in-sql-server-for-tracking-changes/), [here](http://rusanu.com/2006/10/16/writing-service-broker-procedures/), [here](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/31/how-to-prevent-conversation-endpoint-leaks/) and some other places I see the create route step is not always included. For [dynamic routing](http://rusanu.com/2007/07/31/dynamic-routing-service/) seems mandatory of course. Reading on [MSDN-Create route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186742(v=sql.105).aspx) is not clear for me if it is mandatory or not and when it should be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **WMI event alerts** for server events then **service  broker is not required** as it uses Service Broker `SQL/Notifications/ProcessWMIEventProviderNotification/v1.0` in `msdb` and Service Broker is enabled by default for msdb for 2005 and up.

Read up on - [understanding WMI provider for server events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181893.aspx)

---

***To Answer your questions :***

> But I see lot of recommendations to use service broker too. What's the difference between them?

Its your choice to use either Service Broker or WMI Providers for server events. *I find WMI Providers for server events more easy to implement.*

Basically, using Event notifications allows you to capture information **using SQL Server Service Broker** by **creating a service and queue for the events**. *For e.g.* if you set up Event notification to capture DEADLOCK GRAPH then 3 service broker objects are created :

1. A QUEUE to hold up DEADLOCK_GRAPH event messages
2. A SERVICE to route the messages to the queue and
3. An Event NOTIFICATION to capture the deadlock graph and package it in a message that is sent to the Service.

**For WMI Providers for server events** - Any event that can be captured through event notifications has a corresponding WMI Event Object, and any WMI management application can subscribe to these event objects. **SQL Server Agent was updated to manage WMI events**, through the use of WMI Query Language (WQL), a query language similar to T-SQL that is used with WMI and Agent Alerts for WMI events.

> By using WMI I can avoid the hassle of creating service/queues?

Yes but it is in no way a replacement of Service Broker. Event Notification uses Service Broker. WMI Provider for server events uses WMI event objects.

> WMI is broader and allows to track more event types? Or it is something else?

WMI can only handle [these DDL Event Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510452%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Service Broker is much broader.

For monitoring and alerting on Deadlocks, [***you can use my script***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41622/8783).

Refer to : Jonathan's excellent article on [Handling Deadlocks in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/handling-deadlocks-in-sql-server/)