# Collect information about currently running queries only when client timeout occurs

Tags: sql-server-2008, profiler, dmv, query-timeout

We would like to be able to collect information about all currently running queries when (and only when) a client timeout occurs in SQL Server 2008.

I know I can collect information about the client timeouts using the "Attention" Event Class in SQL Profiler.

And I know I can gather information about the currently run queries using `sys.dm_exec_requests`.

But how can I connect these two, i.e. query for all currently active queries only when an Attention Event Class appears?

Would this be possible using extended events (I have never used them, so am not sure about their capabilities)? Or rather some other mechanism?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the blocked process report? It doesn't do exactly what you want but could well be what you actually need dependent on the motivation for the question.

Comment: `Attention` is [its own event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190979.aspx) in SQL Trace. Probably could set up a [notification procedure like this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10560/3690)