# Disabling SET Statements / Forcing SET Options in SQL Server 2008R2/2012

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, permissions, configuration

I am currently working with a MSSQL 2008R2 Database which uses the following SET-Commands frequently:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS { ON | OFF }
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER { ON | OFF }
SET ANSI_PADDING { ON | OFF }
```

While I was researching these Settings I stumbled across the following Note for ANSI_NULLS on Microsofts technet ([Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)):

> In a future version of Microsoft SQL Server ANSI_PADDING will always
>   be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will
>   produce an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work,
>   and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Because of this I would like to enforce a "global" Setting. I have been searching for the better part of a day but as I understand it you can always change these settings. To be completely sure I would like to ask here:

Is it possible to either enforce a Setting like ANSI_NULLS ON or to disable the possibility of changing these Settings on "any" level.
I would like to use this to test if the Database would "survive" if the ability to set a specific option to OFF is disabled.

I hope I was able to describe my problem. This is not my first language.
Thanks in advance.

PS: On StackOverflow I was advised to Ask this Question here too.
Original Question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111978/disabling-set-statements-forcing-set-options-in-sql-server-2008r2-2012)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to enforce a global setting or prevent people running

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

You can get a quick idea if your application is using any deprecated features by running

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE  object_name LIKE '%Deprecated%'
       AND cntr_value > 0
ORDER  BY cntr_value DESC
```

If you do find areas of concern then you could set up a Server Side trace capturing the deprecation events.

[image]

This also returns the session id and SQL Handle of the offending batch to allow you to investigate further if you do see any events.

A slightly more sophisticated approach would be to set up a [notification procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10560/3690) to retrieve the text associated with the SQL Handle more quickly to reduce the probability that the offending SQL is no longer in the cache when you come to analyse the results.

Or you could probably use extended events to retrieve the TSQL along with the event.